# How to change if else to switch case

Tags: matlab, if-statement, switch-statement

I have this code at the moment

```
s=[1 3 4 9 12 16 18 19 20 21];
for k=s   
    if k>2 & k<10
        a(k)=0;

    else if k>10 & k<20
          a(k)=1; 
        else a(k)=2;
        end
    end
end
```

I would like to rewrite this using a `switch, case` statement. How can I do this?

Comment: Why? A switch statement really isn't the appropriate construct to use here.

Comment: Can I Rewrite it or not???

Comment: What if `k==10` ?

Comment: `switch` statements only work if you know the variable will belong to one of a discrete amount of choices. `if/elseif/else` is for handling everything else. It's possible to use `switch` here but that will result in a lot of unnecessary code that the `if` statements capture nicely.  You need to take a step back and ask yourself **why** you need to write a switch statement. If the purpose is to make your code different, that's not a good enough reason.  You don't even **need** a loop here.  You can do this with logical indexing: `a = zeros(1, numel(s)); a(s > 10 & s < 20) = 1; a(s >= 20) = 2;`.

Comment: Is This code OK????  switch k
    case 3,4,5,6,7,8,9
          a(k)=0;
           case 11:12:13:14:15:16:17:19:19
          a(k)=1;
          default : 
          a(k)=2;
end

Comment: @Shayan please note that a single question mark conveys your message amply, there's not need to use three or even four of them.

Comment: @Shayan IMHO that code sucks but it answers your question.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) you can use cell arrays in `case` expression.

```
for k=s
    switch k
        case num2cell(3:9)
            a(k)=0;
        case num2cell(11:19)
            a(k)=1;
        otherwise
            a(k)=2;
    end
end
```

However you often do not want to use if/else or switch/case instead you can use indexing:

```
a(s) = 2;
a(s(s>2 & s<10)) = 0;
a(s(s>10 & s<20)) = 1;
```